# Drupal mail send to multiple recipents

Tags: 7, emails

I want to send the mail to multiple recipents with varying body content each user will have different content . This is the code I used for sending, but I cannot send to multiple users.

```
 $to = 'abc@gmail.com,test@gmail.com';
  drupal_mail('mimemail', 'testing', $to, language_default(), $params, $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user15837 Updated.

Comment: you mean to say with different $params

Comment: yes @ShreyaShetty

Answer (score 0):

This code might be of some help .

```
$to = array('one@email.com', 'two@email.com', 'three@email.com');
        foreach ($to as $key => $mail) {
          if ($mail = 'one@email.com') {
            $to = 'one@email.com';
           $params = array('body' => 'abc');
          }
          elseif ($mail = 'two@email.com') {
            $to = 'two@email.com';
            $params = array('body' => 'def');
          }
          elseif ($mail = 'three@email.com') {
            $to = 'three@email.com';
             $params = array('body' => 'ghi');
          }
          drupal_mail('$module_name', $key, $to, language_default(), $params, $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
        }
```